# Basic Update Statement gets a "1111; Invalid use of Group Function" error on Kace SMA using MariaDB

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm guessing this is something really simple as there's only really 3 lines of code here causing me a problem!

I'm creating a custom rule on the Kace SMA that selects tickets and updates the title field.

For those unfamiliar, the select statement in the SMA pulls your select into the <TICKET_IDS> variable for you to feed to the update statement. In the test area I'm running it in I'm getting ~12 ID's which matches what I would expect.

Select works fine, and then when the update runs via EXECUTE I get *"[1111: Invalid use of group function] in..."*

Both statements below. My initial thought was it's to do with WHERE/HAVING but I'm simply feeding the update a list and not doing anything other than that. I am familiar with standard SQL but hadn't really messed about with MariaDB/MySQL much until now so I apologise if it's a completely basic thing I've done.

```
SELECT HD_TICKET.ID
FROM HD_TICKET
WHERE HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID in (1)
AND HD_TICKET.IS_PARENT=TRUE
AND HD_TICKET.TITLE not like "CR%"
```

```
UPDATE HD_TICKET 
SET HD_TICKET.TITLE = CONCAT('CR', ' ', CAST(COUNT(*) + 1 AS CHAR),' ', '-',' ', HD_TICKET.TITLE)
WHERE HD_TICKET.ID in (<TICKET_IDS>)
```

Comment: The problem seems to be  the `COUNT(*)`, this makes no sense in an UPDATE unless you have a full SELECT subquery in in there.

Comment: You are correct! I'm a muppet. I'm going to just ignore the whole separate SELECT statement and <TICKET_IDS> variable completely.